# Magnolia CMS FilterDecorator

Tags: spring-security, servlet-filters, magnolia

Can anyone explain how the `info.magnolia.cms.filters.FilterDecorator`
is supposed to be used? I cannot find any examples of it. I don't know how to set the `decoratedFilter` property.
I'm asking this because I want to add the Spring Security filter in the filter chain (`info.magnolia.module.blossom.web.InstallationAwareDelegatingFilterProxy`). If I add it directly to the `web.xml` before the Magnolia filter I won't have access to the Magnolia context in a custom `AuthenticationProvider`. If I added after the Magnolia filter it won't be accessed.

Or is there any other way to have access to the Magnolia context in a custom `AuthenticationProvider` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, found it!

In Configuration there's the server/filters node. Under this node create a new folder with your filter's name (ex. springSecurityFilterChain). Create the following content node in the new folder: decoratedFilter. To this content node add a data node with the name `class` and value `info.magnolia.module.blossom.web.InstallationAwareDelegatingFilterProxy`. Under the folder `springSecurityFilterChain` create two data nodes: `class` with value `info.magnolia.cms.filters.FilterDecorator` and `enabled` with value `true` (boolean).
Move the filter under `activation` filter.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, for more details see documentation on [request processing](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/technical-guide/request-processing-and-filters.html)

and [filters](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/reference/filters.html).